# Copy constructor and move constructor has the same run time and move constructor is not being called

Tags: c++

I have a ArrayWrapper class which implements both move and copy constructor.

I have 2 Questions.

1. You can see that in my code, the copy constructor `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper& other)` is exactly same as move constructor `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other)`!? Both works just the same and has the same elapsed time. (I commented out the original copy constructor) How can the copy and move constructor use the same code and still work?
2. The code actually isn't hitting the move constructor (I suspect this is why my first question works), I put a comment in both functions, and the output does not show that the move constructor is being called, even though I am passing an rvalue reference `ArrayWrapper d3(ArrayWrapper(10000000));`. What am I doing wrong?

   ```
   #include <bits/stdc++.h>
   #include <chrono> 
   using namespace std;
   using namespace std::chrono; 
   class ArrayWrapper
   {
   public:
       ArrayWrapper ()
           : _p_vals( new int[ 64 ] )
           , _size( 64 )
       {
           cout<<"?"<<endl;
       }
       ArrayWrapper (int n)
           : _p_vals( new int[ n ] )
           , _size( n )
       {
       }
       ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other)
           : _p_vals( other._p_vals  )
           , _size( other._size )
       {
           cout<<"Move"<<endl;
           other._p_vals = NULL;
           other._size = 0;
       }

       ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper& other)
           : _p_vals( other._p_vals  )
           , _size( other._size )
       {
           cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl;
           other._p_vals = NULL;
           other._size = 0;
       }
       /*
       // copy constructor
       ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper& other)
           : _p_vals( new int[ other._size  ] )
           , _size( other._size )
       {
           for ( int i = 0; i < _size; ++i )
           {
               _p_vals[ i ] = other._p_vals[ i ];
           }
       }
       */
       void generate(){
           for(int i=0; i<_size; i++){
               _p_vals[i] = i;
           }
       }
       ~ArrayWrapper ()
       {
           delete [] _p_vals;
       }
       void print(){
           for(int i=0; i<_size;i++){
               cout<<_p_vals[i]<<" ";
           }
           cout<<endl;
       }

   private:
       int *_p_vals;
       int _size;
   };

   int main(){
       auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
       ArrayWrapper d(10000000);
       ArrayWrapper d2(d); //deep copy
       auto stop= high_resolution_clock::now();
       auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start); 
       cout << duration.count() << endl; 

       auto start2 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
       ArrayWrapper d3(ArrayWrapper(10000000)); //shallow copy
       auto stop2 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
       auto duration2 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop2 - start2); 
       cout << duration2.count() << endl;

   }
   ```

Comment: "I have 2 Questions" - Then you should *ask two questions*. Not bundle them up in one.

Comment: `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper& other)` is not a copy constructor.

Comment: Copy constructor should be `ArrayWrapper(const ArrayWrapper &other)` and should not be modifying `other`.

Comment: @S.M Syntactically it is, but semantically it is not.

Comment: @S.M But what is the point of Rvalue reference if `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper& other)` works the same way? In other words, why bother having `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other)` when you can just implement `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper& other)`

Comment: It does not work for r-values, temp values for example.

Comment: @Because it doesn't work the same way. An non-const lvalue reference vs. an rvalue reference have different potential usage contexts.

Comment: @S.M If you run my example, you will see that `ArrayWrapper d3(ArrayWrapper(10000000));` has the same run time as `ArrayWrapper d(10000000);
 ArrayWrapper d2(d);`

Comment: @Telenoobies Yes because you made the function bodies similar, they have similar run times. What's the issue with that?

Comment: I don't understand why you think two functions that do the same thing should have different performance characteristics.

Comment: @Artyer Yes, I know the function body is the same, but if you can accomplish the same thing using `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper& other)`, then why bother having `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other)` I thought he whole point of rrfer copy constructor is because lvalue copy constructor is slow. But if you can write the same way for lvalue constructor and rvalue constructor, then just write lvalue copy constructor the way you would write an rvalue constructor.

Comment: @S.M.: "*is not a copy constructor.*" Yes, it is. Unfortunately.

Comment: Your second question is a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) so you should just remove it.

Comment: @Telenoobies: Then all of your copying would perform the effects of a move. So how would you be able to copy when you actually want to *copy*? Are you aware of the difference in effects between a copy and a move?

Comment: @Telenoobies the point is not that you should implement them the same. The point is that when you know you are moving you can write something that's more efficient than just a copy and then you write that and it will be faster.

Comment: @NicolBolas I suppose that is an argument for it, but i'm still not 100% convinced... Because you also have copy operator, maybe use copy constructor as a shallow copy and copy operator as a deep copy?

Comment: You may want to read [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)

Comment: @Telenoobies *"maybe use copy constructor as a shallow copy"* - nothing is technically stopping you from doing that, but no self-respecting C++ programming on earth will want to maintain that code. The very point of a copy-ctor is to *make a copy*; not assume ownership. It's in the *name*. Assuming ownership has it's own set of operations (move-ctor and move-assignment).

Comment: Thank you guys, I think my questions are answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both works just the same ... How can the copy and move constructor use the same code and still work?

The body of the function does the same thing, so it works the same way.

Regarding your implication that the copy constructor "works": It is highly non-idiomatic for a copy constructor to modify the operand. Many would agree that it "works" in a wrong way.

P.S. There used to be a smart pointer in the standard library called `std::auto_ptr` which took ownership of pointer passed to the copy constructor. It was an attempt to implement unique pointer before move semantics existed. There is no longer any reason to do that, since we do have move constructors. `std::auto_ptr` was removed from the standard for a good reason.

> The code actually isn't hitting the move constructor ... What am I doing wrong?

You're initialising from a prvalue expression of the same type. `d3` is constructed directly using the initialiser expression of `ArrayWrapper(10000000)` without any temporary object. In other words, only `ArrayWrapper (int n)` is used; not the move constructor.

Prior to C++17, there would be a temporary object which would be moved from as far as the abstract machine is concerned, but even then, the move can be elided, which means the same as above (no temporary, no move) except it is an optimisation that is merely allowed, and not mandated by the standard.

What you're doing wrong is expecting there to be a move, or that the move is guaranteed to have side effects.

Comment: "` d3` is constructed directly from the expression `ArrayWrapper(10000000)`" Which means d3 should be called using move constructor, since `ArrayWrapper(10000000)` is a temp obj which is an rvalue.

Comment: @Telenoobies I changed the wording. Is it more understandable now?

Comment: @Telenoobies See Copy elision here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision  No temporary is created.

Comment: @RichardCritten Can you elaborate on what does it mean no temporary is created? You mean `ArrayWrapper d3(ArrayWrapper(10000000))` only calls the constructor once, basically doing something like `ArrayWrapper d3(10000000)`?

Comment: @Telenoobies yes. It means exactly that.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think my questions are answered.

Comment: @Telenoobies Yes. The compiler sees that it can just create the object directly *in* the destination and does not actually need to do neither a copy nor a move, nor does it need to create any temporaries, so it does exactly that (elides the copy/move). This it is allowed to do by the language standard.

Answer (score 2):

> You can see that in my code, the copy constructor `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper& other)` is exactly same as move constructor `ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other)`!? Both works just the same and has the same elapsed time. (I commented out the original copy constructor) How can the copy and move constructor use the same code and still work?

The only time the copy constructor and move constructor can be exactly the same is when you are dealing with types that are only copyable (or to move them is to get a copy).  This is not what you have.  In

```
ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper& other)
    : _p_vals( other._p_vals  )
    , _size( other._size )
{
    cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl;
    other._p_vals = NULL;
    other._size = 0;
}
```

You basically have an lvalue move constructor.  If you were to print the size of `d` after `ArrayWrapper d2(d);` you would get `0` since you steal its data.  This isn't making a copy and would really confuse a lot of programmers since it does something totally unexpected.  You need to use the code you have in `ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper& other)` if you really want a copy to be made.

Comment: Ok, Thanks!! I understood the first part I think. basically, it's bad programming on my part if I use a copy constructor and change the original object. Thank you, you addressed my first point, but what about the second point? Why isn't the move constructor being hit? Any ideas?

Comment: @Telenoobies Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) a read.  It will explain why no copy/move happens.

Comment: It just says there is a thing called elision, and it's to improve performance. But I'm still not sure why it applies to my example.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, I think my questions are answered.